# How to track execution time of each line / block of lines / methods in PHP?

Tags: php, ide, workflow

Is there a best practice (IDE-based?), a PHP/bash script or something else to

- get the execution time of a line
- get the execution time of a block of lines (for example line 17 to 42)
- get the execution time of a certain function or method

in PHP ? I'm currently stuck with self-built solutions that use `microtime()`, but that's a dirty, unhandy and slow method to do so. I'm especially interested in solutions with the major PHP IDEs like Eclipse, Netbeans, PHPStorm and VIM. A perfect solution would be a tool that tracks an entire application and provides execution time tracking for each line, each method and each custom block of actions.

*I'll provide 50 bounty for a good answer.*

Comment: The magic Google search term for what you are looking for is a "profiler". Take a look at http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler -  however, unfortunately tool recommendations (which is what this boils down to) are considered off-topic for SO.

Comment: I am totally disagree with the reason that this question closed, there is no opinion based answer because he asked about a program it's either exists or not, I don't know why I see some bullshit and blind follow here

Comment: @Akam The close reason I chose was `Off-topic because questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow...` - which this question absolutely does fit into.

Comment: @DaveRandom I agree with this reason...

Comment: @DaveRandom And may I ask WHY asking for a tool/lib is off-topic ? It makes totally sense in my eyes to ask "How to do X / Is there a best practice for doing Z ? I dont think it's opinion-based.

Comment: @Panique I'm inclined to agree with you, but them's the rules. The argument for this put forward is usually one of "it often leads to arguments about with of the available tools is the best" and "this information may be time sensitive, as two years from now it may not include information about new solutions, or the old solutions may no longer# apply"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you are looking for: http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler. You can set up netbeans to attach to php process, than run scripts step by step, watch current variables content and analyze its running times.

Just add dll to other php extension, configure by php ini:

```
; xdebug
zend_extension = "C:\php\v5.4\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9-nts.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
;xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\dev\profilling\"
```

Netbeans setup:

[image]

Then press Ctrl+F5 in netbeans (debugging). Than you can run script step by step and watch current variables values:

[image]

To browse generated profilers log use http://sourceforge.net/projects/precompiledbin/ or http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/ in windows, or http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html for linux.