# Unable to upload JPEG file in the server

Tags: php, html, forms, image-uploading, image-upload

I am trying to upload images in my PHP server using HTML form. I have written the following code. Its not creating problem when i upload a 'png' file, but when i upload 'JPEG' images it says 'Invalid File'. Kindly check it and guid me.

Thanks

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="file_upload_test2.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



</body>
</html>


<?php

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 200000) . " kB<br>";
   // echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }


?>
```

Comment: print $_FILES["file"]["type"], $_FILES["file"]["size"], $extension before if - I think, you'll solve your problem yourself then

Comment: What if I upload `shell.php.png` ?

Comment: what is your image size.. what is upload max size configuration in php.ini check it

Comment: Thanks for the response. There was the problem with max_size_configuration in php.ini.

Comment: @DamienPirsy it says 'Invalid file'

Comment: The script, while insecure (because a malicious user could fake file extensions and MIMEs), is not invalid. Theorically JPEG files _should_ be uploading properly. Make sure you are not trying to upload JPEG files bigger than 200 kb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you host your application on linux, you should convert extension to lower case to match strings in `$allowedExts`, because linux is case sensitive (and not just linux).

Check this [How to track execution time of each line / block of lines / methods in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651854/how-to-track-execution-time-of-each-line-block-of-lines-methods-in-php/17676423#17676423) to be able to run script step by step and see, where the problem is.